# How do I install packages with pip when there are multiple Python versions?

Tags: python, pip

I have different versions of python installed, python 2.7 being the default and 3.2 the second. Now I want to install pyramid to the 3.2 installation. How can I do this?
Just using `pip` to install pyramid does not work, so how can I change the version it is downloading to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options, but either way, you need to get easy_install-3.2. Since it doesn't seem to be packaged, you have to install it yourself. Fortunately that's easy. And you should also get python3-pkg-resources, which is packaged:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pkg-resources
wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo python3 distribute_setup.py
```

Now you can just use easy_install-3.2 to install Pyramid, or go ahead and install pip in Python3.

*OPTION 1:*

```
sudo easy_install-3.2 pyramid
```

*OPTION 2:*

```
sudo easy_install-3.2 pip
sudo pip-3.2 install pyramid
```

Comment: When I run 'sudo python3 distribute_setup.py' it gives a syntax error. Perhaps it's out of date with python3.4 that I'm using?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you want to install specific version of the package with the specific version of python, this is the way

```
 sudo python2.7 -m pip install pyudev=0.16
```

If the "=" doesnt work, use "=="

```
 sudo python2.7 -m pip install pyudev=0.16
```

Ouput: `Invalid requirement: 'pyudev=0.16' = is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?`

```
 sudo python2.7 -m pip install pyudev==0.16
```

works fine

Answer (score 3):

Each `python` binary should have its own `pip` executable.

You get one automatically if you use `virtualenv`. Then you could just run `pip install pyramid` in an activated virtualenv e.g.:

```
$ vex venv pip install pyramid
```

If you want to use `pip` to install for a system `python3` then you could install `pip` for it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

It installs `pip3` program. Then:

```
$ pip3 install --user pyramid
```

installs `pyramid` in `~/.local` directory tree.

If you need to test a Python package on several python versions; you could use `tox`.

Answer (score 2):

**If you get pip3.8 installed this way:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717006/pip-for-python-3-8

**More specifically:**

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.8 get-pip.py
```

Then you can add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```bash
pip3.8() {
  python3.8 -m pip "$@"
}
```

After creating a new terminal session simply install packages with:

```
pip3.8 install xyz
```

Which will place your custom python packages in something like: `/home/youruser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you have installed a separate user-only version of Python by downloading and extracting the tar.gz from the [Python.org Downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/) page and done a:-

```
tar -xzf Python-x.x.x.tar.gz
cd Python-x.x.x/
./configure
make
```

You can use [get-pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to install and run pip *for this Python install only*.

Download it with curl as per the git-pip instructions. Then, within your Python-x.x.x/ directory, run:

```
./python -m get-pip.py --user
./python -m pip install pyramid --user
```